# SEO - две версии сайта - laravel, vue spa

Tags: laravel, nginx, vue.js, seo, spa

У меня сайт  -  backend на laravel, frontent на vue.js - spa.

Сначала делал сайт на простый blade-х laravel.
Потихоньку добавлял vue, потом  полность перешел на vue spa.

Вопрос насчет seo - оптимизацию, прочитал spa - плохо для поисковиков 
google - есть для spa робот который умеет запускать js-скрипты , а вот яндексом беда.

Вот некоторые советует несколько версии сайта для seo - робота отдельный сайт который отдает обычный html, у меня есть как раз версия сайта с  шаблонизатором blade-ом.

вопросы:

1. Две версии сайта простой html для робота и spa для пользователя это норма?
2. Оба версия сайта визуально сильно отличаться, ссылки примерно одинаковые, как этому относяться поисковые роботы?
3. Как лучше реализовать что бы для seo робота открывался сайт c html , а для обычного пользователя spa, Можно это реализовать у nginx  что бы не нагружать сервер?

Comment: а nuxt вам зачем? он решает эту проблему

Comment: говорят он сервер нагружает